# How to make "Analog Stereo Duplex (unavailable)" profile available to enable microphone?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't detect a microphone. There are no sound input devices in the settings.

I tried to use `pavucontrol`. On the "Configuration" tab, I can change the profile of Built-in Audio to "Analog Stereo Duplex (unavailable)". After this operation, there is a new input device on the "Input Devices" tab, and what's more, the sound detector shows that my microphones works.

However, after reboot, the profile changes back to "Audio Stereo Output" and no microphone is detected.
My sound card is "HDA Intel PCH".

I wonder how to make it work? How to make the profile available?

Comment: Try restarting pulseaudio with this command once you are logged on after booting : `pulseaudio -k` Does it get recover the profile ?